The problem of inaccurate valuation of cap by different parameters
My question is that I used two different sets of valuation parameters, but both used December 29, 2023 as the valuation date. One set of valuation parameters is from October 3, 2024 to October 3, 2029, with a payment frequency of quarterly payments and a nominal principal of 10MM. The other set is from September 26, 2023 to September 26, 2028, with a payment frequency of monthly payments and a nominal principal of 35MM. I used the Black model, and my code is mainly intended to replicate the valuation tools in Bloomberg. The Cap NPV obtained by the first set of valuation parameters is very similar to Bloomberg's Cap NPV, DV01 diff = (my mtm - bbg mtm)/bbg DV01 = 0.18. I think the valuation gap of the first set is very small, but the second set of valuation parameters has a larger gap. My result is 84930.053, while the result of bbg is about 152k, which is a very large gap. I want to know what caused this? My VCUB uses the lognormal VCUB in BBG, which complies with the black volatility usage rules. The OIS data comes from Treasury Gov, and the fixing value uses Fedral's 1Day SOFR.
My current guess is that since the valuation date falls between the effective date and the closing date, the added fixings may be incorrect.
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np


# Interpolation function: performs linear interpolation when strikes do not match
def get_interpolated_volatility(strikes, volatilities, target_strike):
    # Ensure strikes and volatilities have the same length
    if len(strikes) != len(volatilities):
        min_len = min(len(strikes), len(volatilities))
        strikes = strikes[:min_len]
        volatilities = volatilities[:min_len]

    # Remove NaN values and ensure length matches
    strikes = np.array(strikes)
    volatilities = np.array(volatilities)
    mask = ~np.isnan(volatilities)  # Exclude NaN values
    filtered_strikes = strikes[mask]
    filtered_volatilities = volatilities[mask]

    # Ensure there are enough data points for interpolation
    if len(filtered_strikes) < 2:
        return filtered_volatilities[0] if len(filtered_volatilities) > 0 else 0.0

    # Create interpolation object
    interpolation = interp1d(filtered_strikes, filtered_volatilities, kind='linear', fill_value="extrapolate")
    return float(interpolation(target_strike))

# Extract Black volatility surface data from black_vol_data
def get_vol_surface_data(black_vol_data):
    expiries = []
    strikes = []
    volatilities = []
    
    # Ensure Tenor column is of string type and standardize
    black_vol_data['Tenor'] = black_vol_data['Tenor'].astype(str).str.replace('Yr', 'Y').str.replace('yr', 'Y').str.strip()
    
    # Retrieve expiration dates and convert to QuantLib Period
    for tenor in black_vol_data['Tenor']:
        if 'Y' in tenor:
            expiries.append(ql.Period(int(tenor.replace('Y', '').strip()), ql.Years))
        elif 'M' in tenor:
            expiries.append(ql.Period(int(tenor.replace('M', '').strip()), ql.Months))
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unrecognized tenor format: {tenor}")
    
    # Retrieve strikes column
    strikes = [float(col.replace('%', '')) / 100 for col in black_vol_data.columns[1:]]
    
    # Extract volatility matrix and convert to percentage format (divide by 100)
    volatilities = (black_vol_data.iloc[:, 1:].values / 100).tolist()

    return expiries, strikes, volatilities

# Create Black CapFloorTermVolSurface
def create_vol_surface_black(black_vol_data):
    expiries, strikes, black_volatility = get_vol_surface_data(black_vol_data)
    volatilities_handles = [
        [ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(v)) for v in row]
        for row in black_volatility
    ]
    vol_surface = ql.CapFloorTermVolSurface(
        0,
        ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE),
        ql.ModifiedFollowing,
        expiries,
        strikes,
        volatilities_handles,
        ql.Actual360()
    )
    return vol_surface, strikes, black_volatility

# Price Cap using Black volatility surface
def price_cap_with_black_vol_surface(black_vol_data, discount_handle, ibor_leg, strike):
    vol_surface, strikes, volatilities_matrix = create_vol_surface_black(black_vol_data)
    expiry = ql.Period(1, ql.Years)
    if strike[0] in strikes:
        expiry_vols = [row[strikes.index(strike[0])] for row in volatilities_matrix]
    else:
        expiry_vols = [
            get_interpolated_volatility(strikes, row, strike[0]) 
            for row in volatilities_matrix
        ]
    interpolated_vol = get_interpolated_volatility(strikes, expiry_vols, strike[0])
    vol_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(interpolated_vol))
    cap_volatility = ql.Cap(ibor_leg, strike)
    engine_volatility = ql.BlackCapFloorEngine(discount_handle, vol_handle)
    cap_volatility.setPricingEngine(engine_volatility)
    return cap_volatility.NPV()

# Set valuation date to December 29, 2023
valuation_date = ql.Date(29, 12, 2023)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = valuation_date

# Build OIS discount curve
discount_handle = build_ois_curve(valuation_date, ois_df)

# Define Cap start and end dates
start_date = ql.Date(3, 10, 2024)
end_date = ql.Date(3, 10, 2029)

# Generate payment dates using Schedule
schedule = ql.Schedule(
    start_date,
    end_date,
    ql.Period(ql.Quarterly),
    ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE),
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
    False
)

# Create IborIndex
custom_forward_index = ql.IborIndex(
    "MyIndex",
    ql.Period("1M"),
    0,
    ql.USDCurrency(),
    ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE),
    ql.ModifiedFollowing,
    False,
    ql.Actual360(),
    discount_handle
)

# Automatically add missing fixing data using sofr_df
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)
for index, row in sofr_df.iterrows():
    date = ql.Date(row['Date'].day, row['Date'].month, row['Date'].year)
    if calendar.isBusinessDay(date) and date <= valuation_date:
        rate = row['SOFR']
        custom_forward_index.addFixing(date, rate)

# Create Cap and set pricing engine
ibor_leg = ql.IborLeg([10e6], schedule, custom_forward_index)
strike = [0.029115]

# Price Cap using Black volatility surface
cap_npv = price_cap_with_black_vol_surface(black_vol_data, discount_handle, ibor_leg, strike)

print("Cap NPV with Black volatility surface:", cap_npv)

# Print payment dates
schedule_dates = schedule.dates()
print("Schedule Dates:", [d.ISO() for d in schedule_dates])

